# XSLT node content showing despite using condition

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i'm stuck on this XSLT that regenerates a specified XML document without showing nodes that have `'top-secret'` attribute, it stills show content of these nodes, here it is:

classified.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="classified.xsl" ?> 
<company_data>
    <data classification="unclassified">item1</data>
    <data classification="top-secret">item2</data>
    <data classification="unclassified">item3</data>
    <data classification="secret">item4</data>
    <data classification="classified">item5</data>
    <data classification="top-secret">item6</data>
    <data classification="classified">item7</data>
</company_data>
```

XSLT Document classified.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="company_data">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*" >
                <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates  />
            
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="data[not(@classification='top-secret')]">
      
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" >
            <xsl:for-each select="@classification">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

[image: img1]

What i don't want:

[image: img2]

Comment: You have overlooked the built-in template rules used to process any elements selected by apply-templates for which there is no explicit rule supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/company_data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="data[not(@classification='top-secret')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. If you want to fix your existing stylesheet, then do not apply templates indiscriminately. Instead of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates  />
```

in the template matching `company_data`, do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data[not(@classification='top-secret')]" />
```

Then you can change:

```
<xsl:template match="data[not(@classification='top-secret')]">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it is working now, Can you explain to me why the method i used didn't work ? Or why should i use an empty ```apply-templates``` ?

Comment: When you use `xsl:apply-templates` without a `select` attribute, you are applying templates to **all** children of `company_data` - including the nodes you want to exclude. These nodes are then processed by the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule) which copy their text to the output.

Comment: Another method you could have used is to have the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template copy everything as is and an empty template matching `data[@classification='top-secret'` to make an exception. But IMHO it is more efficient NOT to apply templates to the nodes you don't want instead of applying templates to them and have the processor look for the empty template.